# How to update the amount on an existing Stripe charge using PHP?

Tags: php

I am working with Stripe's auth and capture. Currently, the charge is $200 upon creating it.

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 20000,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "customer" => $custID, // obtained with Stripe.js
    "description" => "Charge for test@example.com",
    "capture" => false
));
```

But I want to change it to $100 upon capturing the charge.

```
$ch = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve("$chargeID");
$ch->amount = 10000;
$ch->save();
$ch->capture();
```

This part is wrong:

```
$ch->amount = 10000;
```

How would I do this? I'm using PHP.

This should be possible since Stripe's official article on auth and capture mentions it:
https://support.stripe.com/questions/does-stripe-support-authorize-and-capture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have not previously captured the transaction you can set the ammount when capturing like so.

```
$ch = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve($chargeID);
$ch->capture(array("amount" => 10000));
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api#capture_charge

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! And a quick response. I do apologize that I can't rank your answer up since my reputation is less than 15.